# AWS ElasticBeanstalk pull Docker image from Gitlab registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I’m having a hard time to pull Docker image from private Gitlab registry to AWS MultiContainer ElasticBeanstalk environment.

I have added **.dockercfg** into S3 in the same region as my cluster and also allowed to aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role IAM role to get data from S3.

ElasticBeanstalk always return error **CannotPullContainerError: API error (500)**

My **.dockercfg** is in this format:

```
{
    "https://registry.gitlab.com" : {
      "auth" : “my gitlab deploy token“,
      "email" : “my gitlab token name“
    }
}
```

Inside **Dockerrun.aws.json** I have added following

```
  "authentication": {
    "bucket": "name of my bucket",
    "key": ".dockercfg"
  },
```

When I try to login via `docker login -u gitlabtoken-name -p token` it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The gitlab deploy token is not the auth key.

To generate a proper auth key I usually do the following:

```
docker run -ti docker:dind sh -c "docker login -u name -p deploy-token registry.gitlab.com && cat /root/.docker/config.json"
```

and it'll print something like:

```
{
  "auths": {
    "registry.gitlab.com": {
      "auth": "your-auth-key"
    }
  },
  "HttpHeaders": {
    "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.09.0 (linux)"
  }
}
```

Then, as per elasticbeanstalk docs ["Using Images From a Private Repository
"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-images-private), you should take just what it's needed.

Hope this'll help you!

Answer (score 0):

Putting just deploy token in "auth" value also didn't work for me. In the result used such format "deploy_token_name:deploy_token" and encoded it to base64. Used such script in my gitlab-ci.yml

```
export DEPLOY_TOKEN=$(echo "$GITLAB_DEPLOY_USER:$GITLAB_DEPLOY_TOKEN" | tr -d "\n" | base64)
```